# Setting a key's value, changes all the values for all keys

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

When iterating through a dictionary, I'm assigning the value of a key to the matching key of another dictionary, but when I do this, it is changing the value for all the keys in the dictionary, instead of just the matching key entry.

For some reason, this works fine in Sublime but does NOT work when running the exact same code in PyCharm.

```
categories_ranges = {'MILES': 
                    {'CATEGORIES': ['TOTPOP_CY', 'TOTHH_CY', 'MEDHINC_CY', 
                    'AVGHINC_CY', 'BACHDEG_CY', 'GRADDEG_CY', 'MEDAGE_CY', 
                    'FAMHH_CY', 'OCCARCH_CY', 'OCCBLDG_CY', 'OCCFARM_CY', 
                    'OCCCONS_CY', 'OCCMAIN_CY', 'OCCTRAN_CY'], 
                    'RANGES': [[1, 2, 3, 5]]}, 'MINUTES': 
                    {'CATEGORIES': '', 'RANGES': ''}}
organized_output = {
'TOTPOP_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'TOTHH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'MEDHINC_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'AVGHINC_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'BACHDEG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'GRADDEG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'MEDAGE_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'FAMHH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'OCCARCH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'OCCBLDG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'OCCFARM_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'OCCCONS_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'OCCMAIN_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 
'OCCTRAN_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0}, 'MINUTES': {}}
}

for key, value in categories_ranges.items():
    demogs_response = {'MILES': 
               {'TOTPOP_CY': {1: 6639, 2: 22682, 3: 39254, 5: 86086}, 
                'TOTHH_CY': {1: 2834, 2: 9149, 3: 16026, 5: 37772}, 
                'MEDHINC_CY': {1: 53505, 2: 52391, 3: 55267, 5: 67726}, 
                'AVGHINC_CY': {1: 72158, 2: 74334, 3: 80261, 5: 100634}, 
                'BACHDEG_CY': {1: 895, 2: 3221, 3: 5805, 5: 16240}, 
                'GRADDEG_CY': {1: 414, 2: 1508, 3: 3021, 5: 11027}, 
                'MEDAGE_CY': {1: 35.2, 2: 36.4, 3: 37.8, 5: 43.6}, 
                'FAMHH_CY': {1: 1545, 2: 5319, 3: 9072, 5: 20572}, 
                'OCCARCH_CY': {1: 104, 2: 382, 3: 466, 5: 956}, 
                'OCCBLDG_CY': {1: 169, 2: 905, 3: 1704, 5: 1471}, 
                'OCCFARM_CY': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 3, 5: 21}, 
                'OCCCONS_CY': {1: 152, 2: 791, 3: 1264, 5: 1719}, 
                'OCCMAIN_CY': {1: 177, 2: 365, 3: 507, 5: 837}, 
                'OCCTRAN_CY': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}}}

    if categories_ranges[key]['RANGES'] != '':
        for demog_field in demogs_response:
            for category in demogs_response[demog_field]:
                for _key, _value in demogs_response[demog_field][category].items():
                    organized_output[category][demog_field][_key] = _value

print("organized_output: ", organized_output)
```

The output should look like this - which again, works just fine in Sublime:

```
organized_output:  {'TOTPOP_CY': 
{'MILES': {1: 6639, 2: 22682, 3: 39254, 5: 86086}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'TOTHH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 2834, 2: 9149, 3: 16026, 5: 37772}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'MEDHINC_CY': {'MILES': {1: 53505, 2: 52391, 3: 55267, 5: 67726}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'AVGHINC_CY': {'MILES': {1: 72158, 2: 74334, 3: 80261, 5: 100634}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'BACHDEG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 895, 2: 3221, 3: 5805, 5: 16240}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'GRADDEG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 414, 2: 1508, 3: 3021, 5: 11027}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'MEDAGE_CY': {'MILES': {1: 35.2, 2: 36.4, 3: 37.8, 5: 43.6}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'FAMHH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 1545, 2: 5319, 3: 9072, 5: 20572}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'OCCARCH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 104, 2: 382, 3: 466, 5: 956}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'OCCBLDG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 169, 2: 905, 3: 1704, 5: 1471}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'OCCFARM_CY': {'MILES': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 3, 5: 21}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'OCCCONS_CY': {'MILES': {1: 152, 2: 791, 3: 1264, 5: 1719}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'OCCMAIN_CY': {'MILES': {1: 177, 2: 365, 3: 507, 5: 837}, 'MINUTES': {}},
'OCCTRAN_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}}
```

Currently, in PyCharm, the output looks like this:

```
organized_output = {'TOTPOP_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'TOTHH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'MEDHINC_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'AVGHINC_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'BACHDEG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'GRADDEG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'MEDAGE_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'FAMHH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'OCCARCH_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'OCCBLDG_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'OCCFARM_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'OCCCONS_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'OCCMAIN_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}, 'OCCTRAN_CY': {'MILES': {1: 200, 2: 810, 3: 1537, 5: 1955}, 'MINUTES': {}}}
```

When I run this code in PyCharm's debug, I can see every 'MILES' dictionary get its values changed at the same time, which is why every instance of the 'MILES' dictionary has the same exact values. Each entry is part of a different entry so this shouldn't be happening.

I've tried swapping out the `items()` usage to instead use `zip` but that doesn't work either. I tried writing the value assignment process as a list comprehension but that also produced the same result. At the moment, I'm pretty convinced this is an issue with PyCharm. Every alternative method I mentioned above, worked absolutely perfectly in Sublime but I get the same result in PyCharm every time. Currently, I'm running Python 3.6.5, in case that matters.

Am I somehow missing something here or is there some sort of inherent problem with PyCharm that is breaking during the iteration of these dictionaries?

Comment: If I recall correctly you should not use items() to iterathe through a dict and change the dict at the same time.

You iterate through items() and create an intermedieate dict. whenthe loop ends you can try to change / upadte the dict.

Comment: Good point, except for in this case, the dictionary being modified is not being iterated over. Also doesn't explain why Sublime runs it fine while PyCharm doesn't, but thanks for this comment. I'll see if I can make some adjustments to the method.

Comment: It looks like the indentation may be off starting at `if categories_ranges ...`.  What is the incorrect result you are getting?

Comment: @RootTwo The indents were off, but that was more of a stackoverflow problem than in my original code. However, I made adjustments to help clarify a bit more. I'll edit my question to include an example of what the end incorrect result looks like.

Comment: just try `import sys ; print(sys.version, sys.executable); print("\n".join(sys.path))`

If there is a diference between pycharm and sublime, then I guess you'll see a difference in the output of above line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I determined to be the best workaround for this issue:

```
output = {}

if categories_ranges[range_type]['RANGES'] != '':
    for demog_field in demogs_response:
        for category in demogs_response[demog_field]:
            output[category] = {}
            output[category][demog_field] = {}
            for _key, _value in demogs_response[demog_field][category].items():
                output[category][demog_field][_key] = _value
    return output
else:
    return output
```

Rather than trying to assign new values to the keys in the initial dictionary, this forms a new dictionary and rebuilds it as it iterates through the previous dictionaries.